# tools to allow C++ development, with out separate .h .cpp files

Tags: c++, linux, file-organization

I am developing some c++ code, but having code separated in to .h and .cpp is driving me mad, as it is slowing down re-factoring.

Is there a tool that lets one work on a single file. An editor that just hides the truth, or a per-processor that takes a single file and produces the two files .cpp and .h

clarification:
I want a single file per compilation unit (like Java, C♯, Eiffel). I will still have to have #include in files to include the headers of other modules. (but then Java and c♯ have import and using).

clarification 2:

Things are easier if everything that should be together is together.
i.e. one and only one file per class.

Comment: You sure you want to have <iostream> and <vector> and "myheader1.h" and "myheader2.h" and <map> pasted in your source file?

Comment: @Luchian: The way I understand it, he wants to use header files during compilation, but have them automatically generated from the implementation file by extracting prototypes for all non-static namespace members.

Comment: hehe... otherwise it will slow down compilation :)

Comment: I actually think having this separation is a blessing. I don't have to search through the file to find the method I need, going through implementations. (Java, wink wink)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: it isn't. It's a horrible design flaw with countless downsides. The fact that it *can* be used to (imperfectly) provide one single benefit hardly makes it a "blessing".

Comment: @jalf it's not just one benefit. This is the one I care about in every-day work, as it makes my job easier.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore are you saying that having to write a separate .h, relieves the need to have a short-form generator.

Comment: @richard no, because IDK what that is...

Comment: Have a look here for description of short-form http://www.eiffel.com/developers/faqs/eiffel-language.html extract: Automatic documentation: to give the users of a class a precise description of what a class provides, without giving out implementation details, you use the notion of the short form of a class, which keeps the feature headers and comments as well as their assertions, but discards any implementation stuff. For example: …

Comment: What editor are you using that makes editing multiple files difficult?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: yes, but it's a benefit that could be better, and more smoothly, provided by practically any other mechanism, and without all the downsides. A broken compilation model which forces you to write parts of your code twice is not a good thing.

Comment: @William Pursell  have updated question to make it clear that my goal is "one and only one file per class". As for editors, many.

Comment: “say it once”, is one of the core programming design principles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Lzz](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/). I haven't tried it, but it seems like what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 looks to be exactly what the OP was asking for although it is 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever tool you try to use to do this will only hide some of the complexity or make your code C++-unlike and that will in turn make it harder for others to read/maintain.

I recommend that you just learn and get used to the compilation model of the language rather than fighting it. Deciding what goes into the header and/or the implementation is not an automated process, but rather part of the *design* and tools cannot design for you. Any automated tool to do that will end up generating a less than perfect result, probably longer compile times and/or leaking implementation details to the users of your headers.

Comment: I have already learned it. But you ask be to get used to it. Like getting used to being beaten or neglected: this only leads to depression.